# c# Metro framework - Previous and Next button to access another panels

Tags: c#

I am developing this project "Profiling System" using MetroFramework and I've got this problem. If I click the next button I want my system to show the other panels where it has MetroTextboxes, MetroComboboxes, MetroCheckboxes and other tools of MetroFramework, But the panels does not appear.

I also want to try the UserControl just to slide it on the form but I don't know how. Please help.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;

namespace TEST.cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {
        List<Panel> listPanel = new List<Panel>();
        int index;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (index > 0)
                listPanel[--index].BringToFront();
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (index < listPanel.Count - 1)
                listPanel[++index].BringToFront();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listPanel.Add(metroPanel1);
            listPanel.Add(metroPanel2);
            listPanel.Add(metroPanel3);
            listPanel[index].BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without code, we can only guess what the issue is.  You need to provide more than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Why not use its Modern UI Sliding Panel? You need to download the `dot-net-transitions` – A library for animated UI transitions for .NET [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dot-net-transitions/downloads) and also watch this video from the developer of the Metro Framework [Sliding Panel](http://denricdenise.info/2015/08/metroframework-modern-ui-sliding-panel/)